# Calling any() on a generator with print() inside it produces unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, generator

`any` is supposed to short-circuit once it finds a single truthy value in any iterable (whether that's an iterator, generator, list, etc.)

For normal generators, this is true:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> gen = (i for i in range(100))
>>> gen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0341A360>
>>> next(gen)
0                         
>>> next(gen)
1   
>>> any(gen)
True                                                                                       
>>> next(gen)
3                                      
>>>
```

If you create a generate that includes `print` in it, `any` DOES NOT short-circuit:

```
>>> gen = (print(i) for i in range(100))
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> any(gen)
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
...
```

Why does adding `print` prevent `any` from short-circuiting?

Comment: Because `print` returns `None`, a falsey value.

Comment: What were you expecting would happen?

Answer (score 3):

The function `print()` returns `None`. Consider this:

```
>>> gen = (print(i) for i in range(10))
>>> list(gen)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

You can see that the generator returns `None` for each iteration.

`any()` runs until it finds a truthy value. Since `None` is never truthy, `any()` runs to completion.

You can salvage your original code by ensuring that the generator returns the intended value for each iteration:

```
>>> gen = (print(i) or i for i in range(10))
>>> next(gen)
0
0
>>> next(gen)
1
1
>>> any(gen)
2
True
```